# how to detect if array was created from iterator (or array spread)

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

Let's say we have:

```
const foo = [1,2,3];
const bar = [1,...foo,3];
```

Is there a way to know from bar that it was created from items contained in foo?

I thought to use Proxy but bar is init with spread operator, so we can't proxify bar first...

Comment: Why do you need to know that ?

Comment: The question is not the why, it's the how.

Comment: Values are values, the language does not keep "recordings" of what's been assigned from one place to another.

Comment: @8HoLoN We're trying to challenge your premise. You shouldn't need to know, if you're trying to you probably are doing something wrong. And given it's impossible, we could suggest a viable alternative approach if we knew what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: the why is the detection that bar rely on foo array at construction and not standalone value.

Comment: @8HoLoN You could overwrite `foo[Symbol.iterator]` to know when it was used.

Comment: @8HoLoN But what do you need to detect this for? And what parts of the code do you control and which not? Just by looking at the above code, it's obvious that `bar` always depends on `foo`, it's hardcoded. So you're probably asking about some dynamic system? Tell us more about that.

Comment: @Bergi yep, but it does not seem that [Symbol.iterator] method give a reference to bar, it only return an iterator that will be use by bar.

Comment: @Bergi yes I control bith part of code, if it possible so if change happen to foo (detected with proxy), we can know that's we need to re calculate elements of bar (to do a reactive link between two reference (which would be both proxy))

Comment: @8HoLoN So intercept the usage of `foo`, and write `const bar = reactive(() => [1,...foo,3]);`. When creating reactive systems, you either need to be explicit, or employ the  help of a compiler. Notice that you've got the same problem for `const foo = 1; const bar = foo + 1;` or `const foo = []; const bar = foo === baz;` - there is nothing in the value of `bar` that points to the usage of `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. `bar` is a normal array, there is not difference between an array created through an array literal with spread syntax, by `concat` calls, or from `push`ing in a loop.

Comment: by manual pushing, we can know with proxy (proxify the array), by the way

Comment: @8HoLoN Only if you create a proxy before the loop instead of a normal array. The point was that you cannot determine in hindsight. If you were able to control the code that creates the array, you would of course already know how it was created and from what.

Comment: absolutely, so that's why I was wondering if similar approach could be use, not to detect the push, but the spread operator.